# How do I format a tuple of strings?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a database, made by sqlite3:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
                         username TEXT,
                         langFrom TEXT,
                         langTo   TEXT,
                         mode     INT,
PRIMARY KEY (
    username
));
```

Now I want to get a data from it by "SELECT..WHERE" command. For that, i'm making query:

```
def getData(self, **kwargs):
    s = """SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE {} = {}"""\
    .format(tuple(kwargs.keys()), tuple(kwargs.values()))
```

I use this method like that:

```
test_DB.getData(username = 'classtest', langFrom = 'ru')
```

And now I have query, that looks like that:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE ('username', 'langFrom') = ('classtest', 'ru')
```

But I need it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE (username, langFrom) = ('classtest', 'ru')
```

So how should I format my string to do that?

Comment: Wrong idea. The SQL statement has to look like this: `SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE username = 'classtest' AND langFrom = 'ru'`

Comment: I've tested it. It works, when I use  `(username, langFrom)`

Comment: @ttt this might work with Sqlite but it's not standard SQL. Sqlite being an unreliable toy at best, you'll probably want to switch to a proper RDMS at some point, and then you'll be happy to not have to rewrite all your data access layer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First point, your query syntax is invalid, the proper SQL query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE username='classtest' and langFrom='ru';
```

Second point : NEVER use string formattings for SQL queries - this is tricky as you already found out, but more over [it opens your code to SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/).

The proper way is to use your db-api connector's placeholders ('?' for sqlite3) in the query and pass the values as second argument:

```
q = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE username=? and langFrom=?"
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(s, ("classtest", "ru"))
return cursor.fetchall()
```

In you case since you want to dynamically build the query:

```
def getData(self, **kwargs):
    q = " AND ".join("{}=?".format(k) for k in kwargs)
    s = "SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE {}".format(q)
    c = self.connection.cursor() 
    c.execute(s, kwargs.values())
    return c.fetchall()
```

but you might be better using a lightweight ORM like peewee instead of trying to reinvent the suqre wheel...

Comment: Thank you a lot! You can not to worry about injection attacks and reinventment the suqre wheel, I'm doing it only for educational purposes :)

Comment: Well, if that's for educational purpose then _please_ reinvent the wheel - it's a good way to learn indeed - but this doesn't mean you should not learn how to properly use a db-api connector, quite on the contrary! Else you will mostly learn  how to do things the wrong way, and that would be a pity.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
def getData(self, **kwargs):
    s = """SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE ({}) = {};"""\
    .format(', '.join(kwargs.keys()), tuple(kwargs.values()))
```

Comment: Congratulations, all script kiddies will be happy to hack your database.

Comment: But hey, it did answer OP's actual question :P Joking aside, you're absolutely right @brunodesthuilliers that SQL inputs should always be sanitized. Should have given bit more thought to before answering and thanks for pointing why this was a bad answer.